# How can I animate movement of the browser screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

with the following expression the browser screen moves to the element instantly.

```
jQuery(document).scrollTop( jQuery("#myelement").offset().top-500 );
```

How can I do the same thing, but by animating the effect of the movement by a speed?
The following expression does not work.

```
jQuery(document).scrollTop( jQuery("#myelement").offset().top-500 ).slow();
```

thank you

Comment: try `jQuery(document).animate({scrollTop: jQuery("#myelement").offset().top-500}, 'slow')` http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: You can't just append `slow` to the statement and expect that to slow things down. That isn't how programming works.

Comment: no it does not work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anyway it worked like this

```
jQuery(window.opera ? 'html' : 'html, body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery("#myelement").offset().top-500}, 1500, 'linear');
```